# Cómo realizar el promedio de desaprobados en cada instacia SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

¿Cuál es la consulta `SQL` para mostrar el **promedio de desaprobados en cada instancia**?

En la tabla `tipo` tengo las instancia de evaluación: `trabajopractico1, trabajoPractico2, parcia1, parcial2, recuperatorio1, recuperatorio2`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: _Mostrar el promedio de desaprobados en cada instancia_ ¿Qué es lo que buscas? ¿Cuál es la cantidad de alumnos que desaprobaron en cada evaluación? o ¿Cuál es la nota promedio entre los que desaprobaron agrupado por el tipo de evaluación?

Comment: Además, por favor, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta agregando la consulta **como texto**? Jamás pongas el código como imagen. Una imagen sólo sirve para acompañar y aclarar tu pregunta... no el código.

Comment: Además, agrega una descripción breve de lo que hace la consulta, si ocurre un error, agrégalo de forma textual. Referencia [mcve].